# What to do when Data window shows different value then the iCustom value?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mql5, mql, metatrader5

Can someone please give me some pointers/advice on what to do when the data window shows different value then the iCustom value ?
Example : **Buffer 0** and **buffer 1** are showing correct values but **buffer 3 and buffer 2** are showing wrong values
[image]

**Code:**

```
#property version       "1.10"
#property strict

int handle;

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Initialization function of the expert                            |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int OnInit()
{
   handle=iCustom(_Symbol, 0, "LTD by KDMfx");
return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Deinitialization function of the expert                          |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnDeinit(const int reason)
{
   IndicatorRelease(handle);
}


void OnTick()
{
   double LTDindicator1[],
          LTDindicator2[],
          LTDindicator3[],
          LTDindicator4[];
                           
   ArraySetAsSeries(LTDindicator1, true);   
   ArraySetAsSeries(LTDindicator2, true);   
   ArraySetAsSeries(LTDindicator3, true);   
   ArraySetAsSeries(LTDindicator4, true);
            
   CopyBuffer(handle, 0, 0, 75, LTDindicator1);
   CopyBuffer(handle, 1, 0, 75, LTDindicator2);
   CopyBuffer(handle, 2, 0, 75, LTDindicator3);
   CopyBuffer(handle, 3, 0, 75, LTDindicator4);
   
   double val1= LTDindicator1[5] ;
   double val2= LTDindicator2[5] ;
   double val3= LTDindicator3[5] ;
   double val4= LTDindicator4[5] ;
   
   Comment(
   
   "\nBuffer 0: " , val1,
      "\nBuffer 1: " , val2,
         "\nBuffer 2: " , val3,
            "\nBuffer 3: " , val4      
            
            );
return;
}
```

Comment: Are there any settings in the indicator that you have not matched when using iCustom?

Comment: Also, try increasing the `count` value in `CopyBuffer()`